# How to change a button style on magento

Tags: css, magento

I need some help about add to cart and other botton on my magento site.

http://www.siameyewear.com/ray-ban-rb3025-112-69-aviator-large-metal.html

as you can see. It's look too simple for me. I've create a new css button. But the problem is I don't know how to change it with my theme. I already ask theme support to help. but they not support for customized.

```css
.classname {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 2px 0px 0px #ffeac7;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 2px 0px 0px #ffeac7;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 2px 0px 0px #ffeac7;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffce79), color-stop(1, #f7a413) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ffce79 5%, #f7a413 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffce79', endColorstr='#f7a413');
    background-color:#ffce79;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:10px;
    border-top-left-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:10px;
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    text-indent:-2.62px;
    border:2px solid #919191;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:22px;     
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    height:62px;
    line-height:62px;   
    width:143px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;  
    text-shadow:0px 3px 0px #e8ad54; 
}
.classname:hover {  
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #f7a413), color-stop(1, #ffce79) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #f7a413 5%, #ffce79 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f7a413', endColorstr='#ffce79');  
    background-color:#f7a413;
}
.classname:active {     
    position:relative;
    top:1px; 
}
```

Kindly please let me know where do i have to paste this code to make it work. 
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Normally when you change your buttons, you either change the given classname, OR you duplicate the classname and style it from there.

Your Add-to-cart is built around the span containing the text rather than the actual button.

You can style the span by using the following:
.btn-cart span span

In regards to your question i the bottom of your post..
You could override the theme styling, by removing the current style, and then create your own - remember to use the class "btn-cart". Which means, that you could change ".classname" in the CSS you provided to ".btn-cart", however you might need to take a look on the current styling of .btn-cart, especially the .btn-cart span styling. You can paste the code inside one of the included CSS sheets (check your page.xml). Stylesheets is placed in /skin/frontend/x/x/css/

If you want to change the layout of the Add-to-cart button, go to ....../template/catalog/product/view.phtml. From here, you can change your button. Just remember, that there probaly is multiple places from where the add-to-cart button is shown.